# Mips program infinite loop issue

Tags: arrays, loops, mips

I am currently trying to figure out why my mars program for creating an array is getting stuck in an infinite loop. I am trying to create an array using different functions and in the create array function the program is supposed to jump into a get number function and return the value to store it into the array but the counter seems to not be decrementing and it just keeps asking for an element for the array. Here is the code:

```
.data   
str5:   .asciiz "Please enter a number of elements for the array between 0 and 20: "

str6:   .asciiz "Please enter an element: "

array:  .word 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

.text

main:   

begin:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, str5
    syscall

    jal readnum
    add $a0, $v0, $0
    jal verify
    add $a0, $v0, $0
    jal createarray
    la $s1, array
    jal printarray

    li $v0, 10
    syscall

printarray:


createarray:
    add $t0, $ra, $0
    add $s0, $a0, $0
    add $t9, $0, $0

    la $s1, array

loop:
    beq $s0, 0, done

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, str6
    syscall

    jal readnum
    add $t1, $v0, $0

    sw $t1, 0($s1)
    addi $s1, $s1, 4

    addi $s0, $s0, -1
    addi $t9, $t9, 1

    j loop

done:
    add $ra, $t0, $0
    jr $ra

verify:
    add $s0, $a0, $0

    bge $s0, 20, begin
    ble $s0, 0, begin

    add $v0, $s0, $0

    jr $ra

readnum:
    li $v0, 5
    syscall

    jr $ra
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: After re-reading the code, what is causing the error is actually the following code:

```
jal printarray
```

You never did the following code in printarray:

```
jr $ra
```

So, it would go back down to the other functions.

---

## Use the `$sp` (the proper way to handle the `$ra` when calling functions within functions)

<strike>The following segment is the cause of the problem:</strike>

```
    syscall

    jal readnum
    add $t1, $v0, $0
```

Moreso specifically the `jal` call. Calling a function within a function requires some more steps to be taken place.

First, understand what the `jal` instruction is doing. The `jal` instruction, put simply, marks where you currently are and stores it in the `$ra` register. Then, it will jump to that function.

*But there's a problem*: you are already wishing for the `$ra` register to remember where you once were because you, in fact, called `createarray`!

So, you called `createarray`, making `$ra` store where you once were, then within that function you called `readnum`, making `$ra` store where you are in `createarray`. **But now, you have lost where you once were before called `createarray`. So, it will keep looping back to what `$ra` used to be, which is inside your `createarray` function.

Fortunately, the `$sp` register is just what you need

#### How to use the `$sp` register

To store where we are, we push to the stack:

```
addi    $sp,    $sp,    -4 # by convention, we use negative numbers when pushing
sw      $ra,    ($sp)
```

To get where we once were after we called the function (which replaced our `$ra` in the first place), we pop the stack:

```
lw      $ra,    ($sp)
addi    $sp,    $sp,    4 # by convention, we use positive numbers when popping
```

So in the grand scope of things, here is what you do:

```
# push to the stack
addi    $sp,    $sp,    -4
sw      $ra,    ($sp)

jal     theFunctionWeWantToCallInOurFunction

# pop the stack, get back our $ra
lw      $ra,    ($sp)
addi    $sp,    $sp,    4
```

Let's apply this solution to your codebase:

```
.data   
str5:   .asciiz "Please enter a number of elements for the array between 0 and 20: "

str6:   .asciiz "Please enter an element: "

array:  .word 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

.text

main:   

begin:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, str5
    syscall

    jal readnum
    add $a0, $v0, $0
    jal verify
    add $a0, $v0, $0
    jal createarray
    la $s1, array
    jal printarray # comment off this line and you won't have an infinite loop

    li $v0, 10
    syscall

printarray:


createarray:
    add $t0, $ra, $0
    add $s0, $a0, $0
    add $t9, $0, $0

    la $s1, array

loop:
    beq $s0, 0, done

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, str6
    syscall

    # store where we wish to come back to so that $ra can be overriden without losing data.
    addi $sp, $sp, -4
    sw $ra, ($sp)

    # call the function. jal will replace our current $ra
    jal readnum

    # retrieve what our $ra once was
    lw $ra, ($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4 

    add $t1, $v0, $0

    sw $t1, 0($s1)
    addi $s1, $s1, 4

    addi $s0, $s0, -1
    addi $t9, $t9, 1

    j loop

done:
    add $ra, $t0, $0
    jr $ra

verify:
    add $s0, $a0, $0

    bge $s0, 20, begin
    ble $s0, 0, begin

    add $v0, $s0, $0

    jr $ra

readnum:
    li $v0, 5
    syscall

    jr $ra
```